# PHP Cannot redeclare redirect()

Tags: php, laravel, phpbb, phpbb3

I have Laravel running an app and also a PhpBB forum on it. I am trying to do a check to see if the user is logged in using this PHP function which is `\App\Helpers`

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = '/home/clashdata/public_html/forum/';
$phpEx = 'php';
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();

function isLoggedIn(){
    global $user;
    if($user->data['is_registered']){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

And I am using this code in my Laravel controller as the `if` statement.
`if(phpbb::isLoggedIn()){`

But the output is what I get here: http://clashdata.tk/search/livesearch?clanname=clans&location=&trophies=0&minmembers=1&maxmembers=50&clanlevel=0

How come this is happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: It seems that you have to functions with the same name. Laravel has a function named `redirect()` and another one is clearly stated in the error.

Comment: @frz3993 trust me, I can read. But what do I do to fix it is my question.

Comment: You can rename one of them.

Comment: @frz3993 well that would break the entire system would it not...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel and phpbb, and how these frameworks handle the session. If both load files which have functions with the same name it will not be allowed in php, you may need to write codes for each framework to access the session of another. Or you can use something like Laravel_Auth_Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completly sure which version of Laravel you are currently using.. The 5.2 branch (and also older branches..) have an condition around the redirect function, which checks if the function already exists. It seems you removed this part.

Back to your problem:
I checked both redirect functions and if you could savely remove one of them. It seems, both of them do more than just a stupid redirect and I'm not sure if it' save to replace one of them with the other. I've not testet it, but if you want to try it, you should remove phpbb's redirect function, because parts of this function is partly implemented by laravels redirect.

As I'm not sure if you use the complete board software and which parts of them depend on special behavior of the redirect, I couldn't say save, this would work.

If you want a working solution, you could do the following trick. Rename the existing redirect functions and create your own redirect proxy function which call either phpbb's or laravels. But how to decide which function should be called? `debug_backtrace` is your friend. Using this function, you could determine the calling functions filename and doing so you know if the function is called from phpbb or laravel.

```
function redirect() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $calling = $trace[1];
    if ($calling === NULL || strpos($calling['file'], 'laravel/framework/') !== false) {
        return call_user_func_array('redirect_laravel', $args);
    }
    return call_user_func_array('redirect_phpbb', $args);
}
```